# Program Arduino using Eclipse on Mac in 2022

Tags: ide, mac-os, eclipse

I started experimenting with Arduino a few weeks ago. My host is Mac OS and I have used Eclipse for many years, so my first choice is to use an Eclipse plugin. The most recent discussion of the Eclipse/Arduino solution is years old and I have been unable to get anything working.

The marketplace has "Sloeber, the Arduino Plugin for Eclipse". When I try to install this I get these errors:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=_Applications_Eclipse_embedcpp-2022-12_Eclipse.app_Contents_Eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.nebula.cwt,1.1.0.202212191054
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.cdatetime,1.5.0.202212191054
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.oscilloscope,1.4.0.202212191054
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.oscilloscope.feature,1.4.0.202212191054
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.oscilloscope.source,1.4.0.202212191054
```

Comment: for Sloeber problem go to "Install New Software" and change the url for nebula repository to https (or http? I think you need both http and https url for successful install of that component.)

Comment: Thanks, I copied the nebula repository to a 'http' url and installed "Nebula Release all Widgets and Examples" manually from there. Then I installed Sloeber (trusting the certificate) and that seems to have worked. So it is now installed and I can try to figure out how to use it. This was a simple solution and much appreciated.

Comment: It is working!! I created a new sketch, implemented a version of 'Hello, World' for Eclipse and got this output in the console:  
setup 
Eclipse Hello

Answer (score -1):

I am using the Sloeber plugin now. The installation required changing the nebula repository to url to "http" in the "Install New Software" as described by Juraj in the first comment.

However, connecting from Sloeber to the Arduino was unreliable at first. Following Juraj's suggestion, I've been deleting and rebuilding the serial connection after each upload or power cycle to form a connection reliably.

If I forget to reset the serial connection it sometimes forms a partial connection where the host can see serial output from the Arduino but not be able to send commands back.

Comment: what Arduino do you use? for Arduinos with native USB a reset always disconnects USB, then the bootloader connects, then the sketch connects. It is better to disconnect Serial Monitor before upload for Arduinos with native USB.

Comment: It is an Elegoo Mega 2560 R3. I've been doing software for a long time but this is my first attempt to work with hardware.

Comment: so a Mega shouldn't have this problem. I use Sloeber 5 years now and I never had problems with Mega